# How to check if a character matches another character in a char array?

Tags: c++

I'm currently trying to figure out how I can replace a certain character in a char array using a for loop to check each index position in the array. However, when I assign the correct character to the char variable "letterGuessed" and it is checked it instantly goes to the else statement. This leaves the character as an asterisks. This is the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

void hide_Word(char hide[], int size);

int main()
{
    char hiddenWord[] = "Hello";
    char displayWord[30] = { 0 };
    int length = strlen(hiddenWord);

    hide_Word(displayWord, length);
    std::cout << hiddenWord << std::endl;
    std::cout << displayWord << std::endl;

    char letterGuessed;

    std::cout << "Enter a character: ";
    std::cin >> letterGuessed;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (displayWord[i] == letterGuessed)
        {
            letterGuessed == displayWord[i];
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "*";
        }
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << displayWord << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}

void hide_Word(char hide[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        hide[i] = '*';
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: I expect the asterisks to be replaced with the character that has been entered. For example if I enter 'e' I'd expect the for loop to go through the displayWord array and locate 'e' in the array.

Comment: Where is the line that puts an `'e'` in `displayWord` before you enter `'e'`? (For that matter, where would it be done after you enter `'e'`? That appears to be a second bug.)

Comment: can you add sample input and output to the question.

Comment: @JaMiT Could you explain what you mean?

Comment: What is your expected output and current output

Comment: expected output - *e***, current output - ***** (should be an asterisks before the e in the expected output)

Comment: @Wattdog You said that you expect the loop to locate `'e'` in `displayWord`. I asked you to prove that there is an `'e'` in `displayWord`. Otherwise, of course the loop cannot locate it.

Comment: @JaMiT my mistake I think my thought was that I expected that the loop would be able to locate the 'e' in the original array. The original array being hiddenWord.

Comment: @Wattdog If you want to locate a character in the original array, you have to specify the original array. What happens when you change `if (displayWord[i] == letterGuessed)` to `if (hiddenWord[i] == letterGuessed)`? (Be careful. I suspect this will be a subtle change to your output; it's not enough to give you what you want. Count the number of asterisks.)

Comment: @JaMiT thank you I'll give it a try in a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I compile your code I get the warning

> main.cpp|27|warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]

for the line

```
letterGuessed == displayWord[i];
```

This, for one, means that what you do to make correctly guessed letters visible is achieving nothing. Reading and considering warning messages is really helpful, you know.

I guess that your goal here is to turn the "*", which you filled `displayWord` with, should be replaced by the correctly guessed character.
That would better be achieved by an assignment using `=`.

```
letterGuessed = displayWord[i]; /* still unhelpful */
```

But that line would still not achieve anything visible.
To change something in the `displayWord`, it should be what gets the guessed character as a new value, not the other way around.

```
displayWord[i] = letterGuessed;
```

This is however still not satisfying, because you don't do this in the right situation.

Let's have a look at the condition which determines when you do it.

```
if (displayWord[i] == letterGuessed) /* unhelpful */
```

This will trigger, when the guessed character is an asterisk "*", because `displayWord` is filled with asterisks early on.
Which means that the condition only triggers if the user guesses an asterisk, which is unlikely. Even if it happens, the result is to overwrite an asterisk with an asterisk.
The condition you need should not check the asterisk-filled `displayWord`, it should instead check the "Hello"-filled `hiddenWord`.

```
if (hiddenWord[i] == letterGuessed)
```

In total, the code should hence be

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    if (hiddenWord[i] == letterGuessed)
    {
        displayWord[i]=letterGuessed;
        std::cout << letterGuessed;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "*";
    }
}
```

This turns an asterisk in the displayed word into the correctly guessed character at each found position.
Note that I added an output of the guessed letter, to complete the letter-by-letter output. I guess you want to delete that output, or the word-output after the loop, so that the filled in word is only seen once.

Output:

```
Hello
*****
Enter a character: l
**ll*
**ll*
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Yunnosch